# John Tate's Doctoral Thesis

Tags: number-theory

Where can I attempt to read John Tate's thesis (and for possible future use). I have looked everywhere and I only found one website and it requires a payment...

Comment: It has been published as chapter 15 of the book "Algebraic Number Theory" edited by Cassels § Fröhlich (Academic Press, 1967).